# How does this python inheritance hierarchy work? (specific example)

Tags: python, oop

I am working on a code base that uses oop and I am relavtively new to it. My question specifically is, why NewMenuItem not inherit from File?

code bunk to play with code: https://codebunk.com/b/350127244/

"""Build class hierarchy and get values from decendants"""

import inspect

def selftest():

```
class Menu(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Menu, self).__init__()
        self.value = "Menu"

class MenuBar(Menu):
    #having object in there makes it a new style object, which allows us to use super
    def __init__(self):
        super(MenuBar, self).__init__()
        self.value = "MenuBar"


class File(MenuBar):
    def __init__(self):
        Menu.__init__()
        super(File, self).__init__()
        self.value = "File"
        self.FileValue = "File here!"

    class New(Menu):
        def __init__(self):
            Menu.__init__()
            pass

        class NewMenuItem(Menu):
            def __init__(self):
                """
                 Q 1- Why do I need self here?
                 Menu.__init__(self)

                """

                Menu.__init__(self)
                pass
            def show_vals(self):
                print(self.value)
            """
            Q  2 -why wont this work?
            def show_vals2(self):
                print(self.FileValue)
            """

example = File.New.NewMenuItem()
example.show_vals()
"""
Q 3 - Why do I get this error with this line?
inspect.getmro(example)

AttributeError: 'ManageProduct' object has no attribute '__bases__'
"""
```

I'm trying to understand what is happening line by line, but what I don't get is why NewMenuItem doesn't inherit from File.

I tried hard-coding the instantiation of File,like so:
    File.**init**()

but then I get an error unless I pass the File object:

```
File.__init__(File())
```

I guess what I am struggling with is:

-inheritance trees
-super classes
-why we need to hard-code instantiations in this case

Keep in mind that this is the code I have come across. I am not sure why this is the way it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inheritance and scope are two completely different things. `NewMenuItem` is defined inside the scope of the class `New`, inside of the scope of the class `File`, but it inherits from `Menu`, which inherits from `object`. So while `NewMenuItem` will only be accessible through the class `File` and again through `New`, it will inherit its methods from `Menu`, and `super` will refer to `Menu`.

Comment: Thank you that makes so much sense!